# Retry for rxjs in nestjs

Tags: rxjs, nestjs

```
import { HttpService, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class XXXService {
  constructor(private http: HttpService) {}

  predictAll() {
    return this.http
      .post('https://xxxxx/xxxxx')
      .pipe(retry(5));
  }
}
```

then I have the following code to subscribe from the above observable

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { XXXService } from '@api/services/XXX.service';

@Injectable()
export class YYYService {

  constructor(
    private readonly xxxService: XXXService
  ) {
    this.predictAll();
  }

  async predictAll() {
    await this.xxxService.predictAll().subscribe(
      ({ data }) => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      err => {
        console.log('error');
      }
    );
  }
}
```

then I tried turning off my internet connection, Upon checking, 'error' is only printed once in the console which means that my observable is not retrying at all. Is there something wrong that I'm doing.

Comment: @Iueenavarro Why are you wrapping your Observable within a promise by using async/await? This looks to me like a possible root for the problem since i would expect the promise to resolve on Observable.complete(). This link holds some truth https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### It's the expected behavior of retry that is confusing you.

With the `retry` operator, it will not forward the errors to your error handler until all attempts to retry are exhausted. So it's retrying, it's just your expectations are off with how errors are going to be logged. If you want to log errors as they happen *before* the retry, you'd need to use `tap` to produce a side effect before the `retry`:

```js
source$.pipe(
   tap({ error: err => console.log('error: ', err.message) }),
   retry(5),
)
.subscribe({
  next: value => console.log(value),
  error: err => console.log('only fires once ', err.message),
});
```

#### Unrelated: You're doing something odd with async/await there.

Also, it doesn't make sense to `await source$.subscribe()`, because in doing so, your function will just return `Promise<Subscription>`. `subscribe` does not return a `Promise`. You might be looking for `Observable.prototype.forEach()`, however, be warned, using that will forgo cancellation, as it doesn't return a `Subscription` to unsubscribe with.

I'd recommend not using `async`/`await` in this case.

I hope that helps.